# read from nth occurence of string till a specific string

Tags: unix, sed

I have a file with content:

> [ATTRIBUTES]
>   name="name1"
>   default="abcd"
>   [TABLE]
>   name="tabCol"
>   default="abcd"
>   type="abc"
>   [TABLE]
>   name="tabCol1"
>   default="abcd1"
>   type="abc1"
>   [TABLE]
>   name="tabCol2"
>   default="abcd2"
>   type="abc2"

I want to get the specific heading content. Like if i want content of first occurence of heading [ATTRIBUTES], output should be :

> [ATTRIBUTES]
>   name="name1"
>   default="abcd"

Similarly if want the content of second occurence of heading table, the output should be :

> [TABLE]
>   name="tabCol1"
>   default="abcd1"
>   type="abc1"

This i have have to do using unix shell script. I guess that it can be best possible using sed, but dont know how.
So please help.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way you can do it with awk:

*parse.awk*

```
BEGIN { FS = "[][]" }
/^\[/ && f  == n       { exit }
/^\[/ && $2 == heading { f++  }
f == n
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk heading=TABLE n=2 infile
```

Output:

```
[TABLE]
name="tabCol1"
default="abcd1"
type="abc1"
```

Answer (score 1):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and a proper ini file parser :

```
$ perl -MConfig::IniFiles -e '
    my $cfg = new Config::IniFiles -file => "./conf";
    printf "[ATTRIBUTES]\nname=%s\ndefault=%s\n",
        $cfg->val("ATTRIBUTES", "name"),
        $cfg->val("ATTRIBUTES", "default");
' conf
[ATTRIBUTES]
name="name1"
default="abcd"
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^\[ATTRIBUTES]/!d;x;s/^/X/;/^X{1}$/{x;:a;$q;n;/^\[/Q;ba};x;d' file
```

for the first `ATTRIBUTES` block, or:

```
sed -r '/^\[TABLE]/!d;x;s/^/X/;/^X{1}$/{x;:a;$q;n;/^\[/Q;ba};x;d' file
```

for the first `TABLE` block, or:

```
sed -r '/^\[TABLE]/!d;x;s/^/X/;/^X{2}$/{x;:a;$q;n;/^\[/Q;ba};x;d' file
```

for the second `TABLE` block or:

```
sed -r '/^\[TABLE]/!d;x;s/^/X/;/^X{3}$/{x;:a;$q;n;/^\[/Q;ba};x;d' file
```

for the third `TABLE` block.

Answer (score 0):

To only print the second occurrence of the TABLE section:

Not possible in sed, I'm afraid.  Awk on the other hand...

```
awk 'BEGIN { x = 0 } ; /^\[TABLE\]/ { x = x + 1 } ; (x == 2) { print }' foo.txt
```

Of course this stumbles unless your file's contents are just so (i.e. all the TABLE sections are in one run at the end of the file).  To properly implement this as a one-liner requires perl:

```
perl -ne '$count{$tag = $1} += 1 if /^\[(.*?)\]$/; print if ($tag == "TABLE" && $count{$tag} == 2)' < foo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Some like this using `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN {printf "["} NR%2==0' RS="[" ORS="[" file
ATTRIBUTES]
name="name1"
default="abcd"
[TABLE]
name="tabCol1"
default="abcd1"
type="abc1"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MyBloc="TABLE"
MyOccurence=2

sed -n "H
$ {s/$/\
\[/;^s/\(.*\[${MyBloc}\]\){${MyOccurence}\}\(.*\n\)\[\(.*\)$/\[${MyBloc}\]\2/p" YourFile
```

(no session to test here now)